# T-SQL AND logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, logical-operators

I have table TABLE1 with columns A, B and C.  I need to get all rows from the table where columns A, B and C are not all equal to 1, e.g.,

```
WHERE NOT (A = 1 AND B = 1 AND C = 1)
```

This works. However, I need to do this in a fashion that only uses AND and OR statements.  I had expected this to work:

```
WHERE A != 1 
  AND B != 1 
  AND C != 1
```

However, this only returns rows where no row = 1, i.e, too few rows.

Using MS SQL 2008.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
WHERE (A <> 1 OR B <> 1  OR C <> 1)
```

Comment: I think I need to get more sleep!